# Including the created item ID in the response in Azure Mobile Service

Tags: azure, request, response, azure-mobile-services

Basically what I need for my app is to be able to receive the ID of the just created item in an insert operation in Azure Mobile Service. I know that on the server side I can do something along the lines of

```
function insert(item, user, request)
{
  request.execute({
    function success() {
      request.respond(200, item.id);
    }
  });
}
```

I have a few issues with this. First off, I'm completely overriding the default response when I only want to add the id of the item created. Secondly, on the client side, I have now clue how I can access the body of the response when I call MobileServiceClient.InsertAsync

The thing is that modifying responses in operations such as read is fairly trivial but including the item id in the response seems to be way harder. Any ideas on how to accomplish this ?

Further looking into the matter suggests that the data, such as the object returned is already included in the response anyway. How do I get the ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the server side you don't need to do anything - the item to be inserted goes to the server without an id field, and comes back with one. For example, this is a typical request sent to insert data to a table:

```
POST /tables/people HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: ...
Host: myservice.azure-mobile.net

{"name":"John Doe","age":33}
```

And this would be its response:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Type: application/json
Date: ...
Content-Length: ...

{"name":"John Doe","age":33,"id":234}
```

On the client side, you can access the id after the request is completed. If you're using a managed language, that's how it would be done:

```cs
var item = new Person { Name = "John Doe", Age = 33 };
await table.InsertAsync(item);
// When the call returns, the Id field is populated with the id from the server
var newId = item.Id;
```

Or in JavaScript:

```js
var item = { name: 'John Doe', age: 33 };
table.insert(item).done(function(inserted) {
    var id = inserted.id;
});
```

Or in Objective-C:

```objectivec
NSDictionary *item = @{@"name":@"John Doe",@"age":@33};
[table insert:item completion:^(NSDictionary *inserted, NSError *insertError) {
    NSNumber *id = [inserted objectForKey:@"id"];
}];
```

Comment: Blimey! I thought I tested this and the ID wasn't shipped, but I must've made some sort of error (I probably wasn't awaiting for the insert to complete) since the ID wasn't updated. Thanks!